# Apache cgi script invoked from browser but not embedded device

Tags: apache, cgi-bin

I am working on a project that involves two embedded devices, let's call them A and B.  Device A is the controller and B is being controlled.  My goal is to make an emulator for device B, i.e., something that acts like B so A thinks it's controlling B but in reality, it is controlling my own emulator.  I don't control or can change A.

Control occurs via the controller posting GET commands invoking various cgi scripts so the plan is to install apache on "my" device, setup CGI and replicate the various scripts.  I am running apache version 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and have configured Apache2 so it successfully runs the various scripts depending on the URL.  As an example, one of the scripts is called 'man_session' and a typical URL issued by device A looks like this: http://192.168.0.14/cgi-bin/man_session?command=get&page=122

I have build a C/C++ program named 'man_session' and have successfully configured Apache to invoke my script when this URL is submitted.  I can see this based on the apache log:

```
192.168.0.2 - - [24/Jan/2019:14:38:38 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/man_session?command=get&page=122 HTTP/1.1" 200 206 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

Also, my script writes to stderr and I can see the output in the log file:

```
[Thu Jan 24 14:46:10.850123 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 23346:tid 4071617584] [client 192.168.0.2:62339] AH01215: Received man_session command 'command=get&page=122': /home/pi/cgi-bin/man_session
```

So far so good.  The problem I am having is that the script does not get invoked when device A makes the request, only when I make the request via a browser (both Chrome and Internet Explorer work) or curl.  The browsers run on my Windows PC and curl runs on the embedded device "B" itself.

When I turn on device A, I can see the URL activity on the log but the script does not get invoked.  Below is a log entry showing the URL but which that does not invoke the 'man_session' script. It shows a code of 400 which according to the HTTP specification is an error "due to malformed syntax".  Other differences are the missing referrer and user-agent information and http 1.0 vs http 1.1, but I don't see why these would matter.

```
192.168.0.9 - - [24/Jan/2019:14:38:12 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/man_session?command=get&page=7 HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Note that device A is 192.168.0.9 and my PC is 192.168.0.2.  What am I missing here, why doesn't the above URL invoke the script as when issued by the browser?  Is there any place where I can get more information about why the code 400 occurs in this case?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth, I finally figured out the issue.  Steps taken:

1. Increased log level to debug (instead of the default 'warn' in apache2.conf
2. This caused the following error message to show up in the log

[Sat Jan 26 02:47:56.974353 2019] [core:debug] [pid 15603:tid 4109366320] vhost.c(794): [client 192.168.0.9:61001] AH02415: [strict] Invalid host name '192.168.000.014'

3. After a bit of research, added the following line to the apache2.conf file

   HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe

This fixed it and the scripts are now called as expected.